# Using Java Regex to parse a string containing an unknown number of matches into a List

Tags: java, regex

I essentially have a String representation of a comma separated list.  However, each individual element is also comma separated, so the String was modified to have each element surrounded by '<' and '>'.  I am trying to use regex to capture each element and add it to a list, thus making it a List of elements, rather than a String of a List.

Here are some example String inputs:

```
"<>"         // should match regex, but will be thrown out
"<a=1>"
"<a=1,b=1>"
"<a=1,b=1>,<a=2,b=2>"
"<a=1,b=1>,<a=2,b=2>,<a=3,b=3,c=3>,<a=4>"
```

The corresponding outputs I would like would be lists like so:

```
["a=1"]
["a=1,b=1"]
["a=1,b=1","a=2,b=2"]
["a=1,b=1","a=2,b=2","a=3,b=3,c=3","a=4"]
```

The pattern I am trying to use is:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<([^>]*)>(,<([^>]*)>)*");
```

But when I try to create the list, it is not handling each additional occurrence as a new group.

```
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(myString);
if (matcher.matches()) {
    List<String> listOfElements = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) { // group 0 represents the entire String, so start at index 1
        if (matcher.group(i) != null) {
            listOfElements.add(matcher.group(i));
        }
    }
    System.out.println(listOfElements);
}
```

The result of the above test cases are:

```
["a=1"]
["a=1,b=1"]
["a=1,b=1", ",<a=2,b=2>", "a=2,b=2"]
["a=1,b=1", ",<a=4>", "a=4"]
```

Note:  I added the quotes to that result for readability to separate out the values in the list - obviously the System.out.println() does not write out the quotes.

What is the proper regex to do this?  Or if there is a better way than using regex, I'd be happy to hear, though keep in mind that I'd prefer to not have to use a third party package.

Comment: Can you maybe just drop the initial `<` and the final `>`, then split the rest on `>,<` ?  That'll give you what you want in an array, and you can then use `Arrays.asList`.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem ha, well that does indeed work, but seems like too much of a hack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Match the entries one by one with `find` instead of `matches`.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<([^>]*)>");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(myString);
List<String> listOfElements = new ArrayList<>();

while (matcher.find()) {
    listOfElements.add(matcher.group(1));
}
System.out.println(listOfElements);
```

Comment: This is definitely close to what I'm looking for, but the return values are keeping the brackets for some reason (maybe since it's just group()?). I could technically just replace the brackets with nothing, but there's prob a better way

Comment: @Sean Made a typo. Try it again.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in one line by splitting using look arounds:

```
String[] parts = str.split("(?<=>),(?=<)");
```

The regex splits on commas that are preceded by `>` and followed by `<`, without consuming the angle brackets.

If you really need a List:

```
List<String> parts = Arrays.asList(str.split("(?<=>),(?=<)"));
```

Comment: sure enough, that works.  I like the regex that Leo gave a little better, but it's still good to know about this way! thanks